# Send Form Name in POST parameters in iOS

Tags: html, ios, objective-c, afnetworking

I want to send form name also in the post parameter, 
Html eg :

```
<form id='form1' name='ecom' action='abc.com' method='POST'>`
<input Parameters .... /> </form>
```

Current method I am using this:

```
    NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];     
    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu",(unsigned long)[postData length]];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:baseUrl]];   
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Current-Type"];
    [request setHTTPBody:postData];
```

Here this is working fine for posting parameters but I also need form name to be sent.

Comment: what if you add another header field for form name

Comment: Can you give me an example or so ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can send name in post body something like this

```
NSString *post = @"formName=<name>"; // add any other parameters you want
NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
[request postData]
```

;

Comment: is this the code you mean ? 

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
NSString *postForm = @"formName='ecom'";
NSData *postFormData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
[request setHTTPBody:postFormData]; 

I doubt on the [request setHTTPBody:postFormData] will this work ?

Comment: yes same as you are doing already, or you can send it via httpHeaderField as well same like you are sending Current-Type

Answer (score 0):

You can send the form name in your request header

```
[request setValue:@"yourformname" forHTTPHeaderField:@"form-name"];
```

Hope that helps.